# Check if Python3 is installed without misleading macOS installation window

Tags: python, macos

I've tried to google and have failed to find any answers.

I'm trying to check if Python 3 is installed and its version.

I'm using this command:

```
python3 --version
```

Unfortunately, in case `Python 3` is NOT installed, this command produces this window instead of just printing some error message to the console:

[image]

> The python3 command requires the command line developer tools. Would
> you like to install the tools now?

This unwanted window makes our users think that our app needs them to install this stuff and they do install all of it, which includes `XCode`, which they don't need actually.

Is there a way to suppress this window?

**Addition #1**. For now, I'm thinking about just using `which python3` command. If it says `/usr/bin/python3` - Python 3 is NOT installed. Is it good solution? If Python 3 is installing by means of standard installer, then this command outputs this path (at least on my machine): `/usr/local/bin/python3`. I'm curios if some other type of installation (e.g. homebrew) can just replace this `/usr/bin/python3`. It seems that should never happen, but I'm not sure.

**Addition #2**. OK, I've checked that `XCode` replaces this `/usr/bin/python3` dummy when it installs Python 3. So the solution in Addition #1 will not work.

**Addition #3**. It seems that this `/usr/bin/python3` dummy is not replaced by `XCode`. This dummy is just searchs for the actual Python binary installed by XCode, e.g. in this path: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3`. If it finds it - it launches it. In case of failure, it shows this window.

**So, it seems that the working solution would be to check if `which python3` command says `/usr/bin/python3`. If no - we just can safely try to launch `python3 --version`. If yes - we need to check if `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3` exists. If yes - again we can safely launch `python3 --version`. If no - `Python 3` is NOT installed.**

Comment: [Bash Shell Find Out If A Command Exists](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-shell-find-out-posixcommand-exists-or-not/)

Comment: @LeiYang How can this help? The command does exist. Always. And it shows this message.

Comment: The standard system Python gets installed in `/usr/bin/python3`.  The one in `/usr/local/bin` is probably from HomeBrew.

Comment: @TimRoberts What do you mean? In "standard" macOS installation there is just a dummy on this path which shows this installation window. Do you mean that XCode installer replaces this dummy with the actual Python 3 binary?

Comment: Everything in my `/usr/bin`, including python3, has the same timestamp, at the point where I installed Monterey.  Maybe it did that because I had installed XCode previously.

Comment: I have Monterey also and it does NOT have Python 3 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the working solution is to check if `which python3` command says `/usr/bin/python3`.

If no - we just can safely try to launch `python3 --version`.

If yes - we need to check if `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3` exists.

If yes - again we can safely launch `python3 --version`.

If no - `Python 3` is NOT installed.