# Swift get real python3 installation path

Tags: python-3.x, swift, macos, macos-monterey

MacOs application needs to get path to python 3 without showing window

> The python3 command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?

to run the python script, otherwise show a message about the need to install python3 (like `https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/`)

used links [Check if Python3 is installed without misleading macOS installation window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71135503/check-if-python3-is-installed-without-misleading-macos-installation-window)

```
private let devPython3Path = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3"
private let defaultPython3Path = "/usr/bin/python3"

private var python3Path: String? = nil

func callShellComand(launchPath: String, arguments:[String]) -> String {
    do {
        let process = Process()
        let outputPipe = Pipe()
        let errorPipe = Pipe()
                    
        process.launchPath = launchPath
        process.arguments = arguments
        process.standardInput = nil
        process.standardOutput = outputPipe
        process.standardError = errorPipe
        
        if #available(macOS 10.13, *) {
            try process.run()
        } else {
            process.launch()
        }
        
        process.waitUntilExit()
        
        let data = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        return (String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
                .trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    } catch {
        return ""
    }
}

func getPython3Path() -> String {
    
    if (!python3Path.hasValue()) {
        let whereResult = callShellComand(launchPath: "/bin/zsh", arguments: ["-c", "where python3"])
        if (!whereResult.isEmpty) {
            let paths = whereResult.split(separator: "\n")
            debugPrint(paths)
            showMessage(message: "where_result: " + whereResult)
            if let anotherPath = paths.first(where:{ 
                    $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                      .caseInsensitiveCompare(defaultPython3Path) != .orderedSame
                }) {
                let anotherPathString = String(anotherPath)
                if (fileSystemProvider.isFileExists(path: URL(fileURLWithPath: anotherPathString))) {
                    python3Path = anotherPathString
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!python3Path.hasValue() 
        && fileSystemProvider.isFileExists(path: URL(fileURLWithPath: devPython3Path))){
        python3Path = defaultPython3Path
    }
    
    if (!python3Path.hasValue()) {
        python3Path = ""
    }
    
    showMessage(message: "return:" + python3Path!)
    debugPrint("getPython3Path return:\(python3Path!)")
    return python3Path!
}
```

When the application is normally launched by double-clicking
executing the `where python3` command returns the result:

```
/usr/bin/python3 #dummy
```

when launching application via terminal `SomeApp/Contents/MacOs/SomeApp`
command execution returns:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 # and/or /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3 #dummy
```

Tested on MacOs 12.1.
Is it possible to get the path to the actual installed python3 when running the application normally?
Why is the result different?
How can I get the correct python3 installation path?

Comment: Not sure I understand this. There could easily be many Python3 interpreters installed anywhere in the filesystem - which is the *"correct"* one? Why are you executing a Python process anyway - if you want to know if Python is  installed at `/some/path/python` you can test if that file exists and is executable, surely?

Comment: I mean `where python3` not return `/usr/local/bin/python3` or any other paths, if application execute normally `Application->SomeApp` via double-click on app.